# Retrieving an entity from CRM 4.0

Tags: plugins, crm

Whenever there is an update in any entity on CRM , only the updated fields of that entity are passed to corresponding plugin in addition to its ID. i want to retrieve the entity with all the fields from CRM. It turns out that I can do that by using the following code

```
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

so when i retrieve the entity as follows

```
service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, cols);
```

it returns data type "Entity". How can I change it to lets say contact or account.
if I use some thing like this

```
service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, cols).ToEntity<contact>()
```

...it does not recognize contact.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to read data from the entity:

Entity e =  service.Retrieve(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, cols);
var x = e['attribute_to_read'];

You will have to type cast the data.